# Link to my Apps in AppStore in Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store

I want to add link to my other apps in App Store from Phoengap app.

I tried open in webview this URL:

http://itunes.com/apps/bjango

By this article
http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/

But not working for me. Child browser window is opened, but nothing is shown on display.

How to do it correctly?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the URL that you are opening so that it is in this format

`itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/<yourappdevelopername>`

Replace `<yourappdevelopername>` with the developer name that you have registered with Apple.

Comment: what is yourappdevelopername?

Comment: The developer name that you have registered with Apple. Answer updated.

Comment: Where can i find my developername?

Answer (score 26):

Here is the correct way to link to the App Store in PhoneGap:

```
<a href="itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id<app apple id>">To App Store</a>
```

And for Android:

```
<a href="market://details?id=<bundle id>">To Google Play Store</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the user is on android or iOS so I can keep one build of my app?

Comment: @Mike You can detect platform by using Cordova's device plugin. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Even tho this is an old thread... Mike has been asking if there's a way to detect whether we're on iOS or Android platform.

In Phonegap/Cordova you can call

```
device.platform
```

which will, for example, return the value

> iOS