# Redirect app to the ios store using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I have a phonegap application on ios store.
i want to redirect the user to the ios store but its not working.

i used this in javascript:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
```

and it was working fine , i got redirected to google.

but if I use this in javascript:

```
window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8&uo=4";
```

it works on chrome , but on iphone it skips it ! and nothing happens.
is it restriction from apple on phonegap? .. because i've seen native apps redirects you to the ios store. but i dont know if that is allowed in phonegap or cordova applications.

also it skips it if i did an ajax call on the itunes link and goes directly to the error.

Comment: Did you try formatting it more like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670026/link-to-my-apps-in-appsrore-in-phonegap)?

Answer (score 7):

Use Phonegap In app browser

```
 window.open('https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8&uo=4', '_system');
```

before that you must add plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```